# В Pycharm не показывает окошко "add file to git" при создании нового файла

Tags: git, pycharm

Как его вернуть, случайно нажал «не спрашивать больше»,  теперь по умолчанию все добавляется в git

Answer (score 3):

В настройках Version Control -> Confirmation -> "When files are created"  (когда файл создан) меняете "Add silently" (добавлять "молча") на "Ask" (спрашивать).

Скриншот из IntellijIDEA, но все аналогично будет для всех IDEA-подобных IDE.

[image: Скриншот окна настроек]